# Android Date Time Format getting wrong time to display 12 hours and 24 hours

Tags: android, datetime

Here I found some problem to maintain one simple date response to get 12 hours and 24 hours. Both time are different in one date format.
Code which I have used currently:

> My Date String Response = "2011-12-12T19:41:15.17Z"

## Code

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatToolTipResponse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

private SimpleDateFormat cunsultationPostTimezone12 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a z");
private SimpleDateFormat cunsultationPostTimezone24 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:MM z");


public String formateDateTimeConsultation(String dateTime)
    {
        StringBuffer strResult = new StringBuffer();
        strResult.append(getPostTimecunsultation(parseDate(dateTime)));
        return strResult.toString();
    }
private static Date parseDate(String date)
        {
        try {
            return dateFormatToolTipResponse.parse(date);

        } catch ( Exception e ){
            return null;
        }
    }
private  String getPostTimecunsultation(Date date)
         {

        if(date != null){           
            if(ConstantCodes.is24Hours)
                        {       

                return cunsultationPostTimezone24.format(date);
            }
            else
                        {               
                    return cunsultationPostTimezone12.format(date);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

========================================
**Here is my output**

```
24 hours = 12/12/11 11:12 PST
12 hours = 12/12/11 11:42 AM PST
```

I couldn't find what's wrong in this.
Please can you suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you set the MM in the time in 24 format

```
private SimpleDateFormat cunsultationPostTimezone24 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:MM z");
```

so you always getting Month value Caps M will give you the Month value while small m for minute change with this below line and then try

```
private SimpleDateFormat cunsultationPostTimezone24 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm z");
```